# Sort three input values by order

Tags: c++, beginner, sorting

This is a program to sort three inputted integers in order, from least to greatest. I would like to have it reviewed.

```
#include <iostream>

void Sort(int &a, int &b, int &c){
    if(a>b){
        int tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
    if(a>c){
        int tmp = a;
        a=c;
        c = tmp;
    }
    if(b>c){
        int tmp = b;
        b=c;
        c=tmp;
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "Enter three integers: " << std::endl;
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;

    int output1 = num1;
    int output2 = num2;
    int output3 = num3;

    Sort(output1,output2,output3);

    std::cout << num1 << " " << num2 << " " << num3 << " "
         << " in sorted order: ";
    std::cout << output1 << " " << output2 << " " << output3 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Things you should change:

1. `Sort()` is explicitly returning at the end (`return;`). The return statement is implicit once you reach the end of a void function, so should not appear.
2. Pay attention to the spacing between the `=` sign. In some places you have `b=c;` while in others you have `a = b;` Be consistent with the spacing. I suggest the latter, as it seems more readable to me.
3. You don't have to `return 0` from main. For `main()`, the return zero is implicit if not added.

---

This is also a great opportunity for you to learn about C++ templates. I will suggest you a base implementation that you can study, test, and better understand the awesomeness of this language feature:

```
template<typename T>
void swap_if_greater(T& a, T& b)
{
    if (a > b)
    {
        T tmp(a);
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }
}

template<typename T>
void sort(T& a, T& b, T& c)
{
    swap_if_greater(a, b);
    swap_if_greater(a, c);
    swap_if_greater(b, c);
}
```

Just as in the example provided by @EngieOP, I've added a swap function to reuse more code.
I've also better separated common code by moving the conditional inside the swap function (`swap_if_greater()`), since it is common to all inputs.

`sort()` is now a template function, meaning is can operate on any type, including `int`, `float`, `double`, `char`, ... It is a *generic* function, just as many of the functions in the standard C++ library. This concept promotes great code reuse and low redundancy of functionality.

Comment: I would recommend using `std::swap` instead of implementing it in `swap_if_greater`.

Comment: Concerning `return 0;` from `main`, I've always thought that leaving it out looks wrong. That feature is there to make `hello, world` simple for beginners, but there's no harm in putting the `return` statement in, and no need to remove it if it's there.

Comment: @PeteBecker, Adding the return 0 on main always seemed to me like adding the return at the end of a void function. Seems like boilerplate code to me. But I'll agree that opinions may vary on the subject.

Comment: @glampert - but `main` isn't a `void` function; it returns `int`, and the returned value is detectable by the caller. Leaving out the return is a convenience.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `std::swap` to swap values, and it will shorten the `Sort` method by quite a bit:

```
void Sort(int &a, int &b, int &c){
    if (a > b) {
        std::swap(a, b);
    }
    if (a > c) {
        std::swap(a, c);
    }
    if (b > c) {
        std::swap(b, c);
    }
}
```

Tip: the program will be a little bit easier to test if you allow the input as command line arguments too, in addition to stdin:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int num1, num2, num3;
    if (argc >= 4) {
        num1 = std::stoi(argv[1]);
        num2 = std::stoi(argv[2]);
        num3 = std::stoi(argv[3]);
    } else {
        std::cout << "Enter three integers: " << std::endl;
        std::cin >> num1 >> num2 >> num3;
    }
```

*Thanks to [@glampert](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39810/glampert) for recommending the modern `std::stoi` instead of `atoi`!*

Comment: I would recommend replacing `atoi` in your example with `std::stoi`, which is the new standard. It is very likely that the OP will have a C++ compiler by now.

Comment: @glampert: well, you can tell by the OP's use of references in the question.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA, that was a typo, I meant a **C++11** compiler. Of course the code in question was C++ :)

Answer (score 6):

Notice how the function `Sort()` is performing the same operation on three different pairs of variables?
I suggest writing a separate function called `Swap()`. This shortens and simplifies the code.

`Swap()` can be something like this:

```
void Swap(int &x, int &y){
    int tmp = x;
    x = y;
    y = tmp;
    return;
}
```

Your `Sort()` function should look like this:

```
void Sort(int &a, int &b, int &c){
    if(a>b){
        Swap(a,b);
    }
    if(a>c){
        Swap(a,c);
    }
    if(b>c){
        Swap(b,c);
    }
    return;
}
```

Instead of declaring three more integers to hold the output, do the following. You're passing references to avoid copying anyway.

```
std::cout << num1 << " " << num2 << " " << num3 << " in sorted order: ";
Sort(num1,num2,num3);
std::cout << num1 << " " << num2 << " " << num3 << std::endl;
```

I'm sure other reviews may show examples of using `C++11` to simplify things.

Comment: I thought it was simple enough that I didn't have to write a separate function.

Comment: Okay. For a program this simple, you can do without writing a separate function. But do you really want to do all that extra typing? Plus, it looks cleaner don't you think?

Comment: You could just use templated [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), which accepts any type, not just `int`s.

Comment: Yes. :) But since we're including `algorithm`, might as well just use `std::sort`. To what extent do we hold back for a `beginner` tagged question?

Comment: @EngieOP: Sure, a beginner can learn how swap works, but using the STL version results in less code and less to maintain.

Answer (score 6):

First off this is pretty good for a beginner. These are some notes that mostly say *use the build in standard library* which you are not familiar with yet.

- I dislike the variable declarations

  ```
  int num1;
  int num2;
  int num3;
  ```

  Those 3 numbers belong together:
  `std::array<int, 3> numbers;`.
  An alternative would be `int numbers[3];`.
  `std::array` has some advantages such as having a `size` method and it can be passed as a parameter. Build in arrays will decay to pointers instead.
- You do not need to invent your own sorting algorithm, use `std::sort`.
- You do not check for read errors. If `std::cin` fails to read the numbers your program will output garbage.

Complete program:

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Enter three integers:\n";
    std::array<int, 3> numbers;
    for (auto &n : numbers){
        if (!(std::cin >> n)){
            std::cout << "Failed reading number\n";
            return -1;
        }
    }
    for (auto &n : numbers){
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << " in sorted order: ";
    std::sort(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers));
    for (auto &n : numbers){
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```